# uploadedFile comes null in the bean at p:fileUpload

Tags: jsf, primefaces, upload

I am using primefaces p:fileUpload in simpleMode. When I upload any file in the frontend, I see null for the file upload in the bean side(backing side). You can see the sample code below. I would be glad if you can help me .

Sample Code:

```
<h:form id="welcomeForm">
<p:fileUpload value="#{hashRaporBean.file}" mode="simple" />
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{hashRaporBean.upload}" ajax="false" />
<h:message for="welcomeForm" />
```

Bean Code :

```
@ManagedBean(name = HashRaporBean.BEAN_NAME)
@ViewScoped
public class HashRaporBean implements Serializable {
private UploadedFile file;

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public void upload() {
    if(file != null) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you do to debug the issue? Did you step through the code to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I dont very well known about h taglib,
May be because of encrypt not added

`<h:form id="welcomeForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >`

same as , [click here](http://www.developersbook.com/jsf/jsf-tags-reference/html/form.php)

Comment: Hello Parth. It does not change even I add encytpe. I come across with the same error . Do you think ui:define or ui:composition neutralize this issue ?

Comment: Nope, i can not find any solution for this. i hope link provided in answer helps you. thnx